# MySQL dump restore delta only

Tags: mysql, restore, dump, delta

At work we have a script that does a mysql data dump everynight. For development we usually need to work with data from the most recent dump. We kept doing a database restore every day for some time but now we are getting to a point where the restore is taking close to an hour everyday. Is there a way for us to do a delta restore in mysql or maybe just do a delta dump. Kind of like a patch file but for mysql. Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

-Hrithik

Comment: you **recreate** your database everyday? or you append new information?

Comment: have you checked http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [incremental backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) will probably be your best option. Using a log file it creates something similar to a patch file.

If both servers are running the same version of MySQL you can simply [copy the MySQL files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html).

Comment: You can simply copy the MySQL if using MyISAM not InnoDB.